# Can switch default statement be optimised out for enum

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer, c++20, compiler-optimization

If I have a switch statement that handles all enum cases explicitly, is the compiler allowed to optimise away the default case statement?

```
enum MyEnum {
 ZERO = 0,
 ONE = 1,
 TWO = 2,
 THREE = 3,
};

bool foo(MyEnum e) {
 switch(e) {
 case ZERO:
 case ONE:
 case TWO:
 case THREE:
  return true;
 default:    // Could a compiler optimise this away?
  return false;
 }
}
```

[Cpp Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) says regarding enums (emphasis mine):

> Values of integer, floating-point, and enumeration types can be converted by static_cast or explicit cast, to any enumeration type. **If the underlying type is not fixed and the source value is out of range, the behavior is undefined**. (The source value, as converted to the enumeration's underlying type if floating-point, is in range if it would fit in the smallest bit field large enough to hold all enumerators of the target enumeration.) Otherwise, the result is the same as the result of implicit conversion to the underlying type.
>
> Note that the value after such conversion may not necessarily equal any of the named enumerators defined for the enumeration.

Which indicates it would be allowed to optimise out the default statement in the above example since the underlying type is not fixed and every 2-bit value is specified (though maybe you would need to include negative values to -4).

However, it is not clear if this also applies to fixed type enums or enum classes.

---

In practice, GCC, clang, and MSVC do *not* assume that the enum is one of the defined values.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAnKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdF6CrX1jVktQ929RSUSAJS2qF7EyOwcjD4A1ACyAJ7YDJsmAOxWGgCCGwBa2ABKAPIbJgDMACIbGqQm5xt3odiPrw2LS%2BFwAKgB1B7PN5mT7fUEACRu2H%2B0I2TzhZ2OL2epyx5wiqE8G34qAgu32m0ws0eJxBGwUAHdCMgEBBqbS8RtREorrc7iB6TzMD8/oLvsKNhCBUKmLzEcjsOKLhtiJgCEsGBsCMQvJhcfSsFQmF5aAQQBsAPSWjYeU3obUIEVoFgJOjRDaoBKOFh4XkEBB%2BjZMRlMHbPABi9NV6s1JLESgN32xIJT5w481onAArLw/BwtKRUJw3NZrAzFssReYnjxSOaCxn5gBrEBPSQAOiOsSOkgAbLEyhonrENFI%2B/pOJI85peMWOLwFCAPg2tPM4LAYIgUKhXe6yBQIC63fQYsgDEYuNmNB8sAA3PArABqeEwjLuCUYnDrNDN0SXEARLOpARMEdQ7N%2BvAumwgh3AwtAQY2pBYCwhjAOISH4GqVR3pgS5IZgqiVF4BCrHWwSkVmSG0HgETEOBHhYMBOp4CwkHzFQBjAAoL5vh%2BX7cLw/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqEhugtBexhlpY%2Bi0UukDzF6HT4QAtHcTwbDp4JiLQhlDOg0KmJY1hmIWFRVM47IMO4nhNP4zlTP0pSJMkqQCKMzQ%2BbkaSecUAzjG0lQdF0IyuWMrTtNUww9MEfRhd5EyxZkgWZSlhReXMCxLCshVUbmpD5oW84bKoAAcfY6X2kjcopQLZh2GgdRsEC4IQJCPGYtazLwq5NqQra1h29WDj2khHH2ZjzdmZgTlR06kGx14VcB86Lsu9azuuW4QEgx77uQlBnaeIB3sgCQJAA%2BneZQPU8TwPaoTXIZgD7Pq%2B76fvmP50KRxAAUBSGgcwxCIXW0GMAQcEIcBKFoRhhZYVFeC4fhhaEcRpGQeQghtMBNF0QxGCrIWLFsYJHFcTx/38UDQmyKJ4gScJ8hKGowG6BiikoMpNjk%2BpECad6aS6XcZhWuZwvWZYtmLpFDl%2BE5LnZe56ChTMLQ5H56RxYFhsdHr4UJVjAgxQ0JuDGr0XJRbGXJQFgzO6l0zhfMCiViVXCZjmM5IdVn3NSwCi3Rsz2xB2b3db1RDEANQ0jYd8xOkwWAxBLk4cOtm0fJVc6cHtK4Z%2BNbZcFNA5lL282LX2y2rZwTwh1VZcHY2R3wCdO57qeF1HruJ4DHULBNcAXBmLZ32/ZgvEAwJwN/mDlAQ4WUPgUT8OwfBiEY5gqFGOjvCYzheHAfjyAkWRvAUaT1G0fRMOMdTI3EKx7F8IzS8s0TbmHNxLSG5tJPmckQCwiFlZKwKkxbwEltpTgekDJGRMmZAgFlXiwJsnZR2aQXDOXdi0QIXsCoG18h0EhQUjYuwdolG2bt7YRUYZ0T2%2BV0oe26DQ3K9DA5FSrKVYO21Q6cA2GcG4WwmobGAMgZAQIzAdiURoRO%2BBk6p0DunHuLY2xPHjm9QxRijH53WiXIsXclwVx0fnMwHdS4Lm7mueYuEwaEMkEAA) with full optimization enabled like `-O3 -std=c++20`.)

Is that a missed optimization, or is the standard saying that if the implementation picks `int` as the underlying type (even though you didn't specify) then any `int` value is legal?

CppReference shows an example under the paragraph quoted:

```
enum access_t { read = 1, write = 2, exec = 4 }; 
 // enumerators: 1, 2, 4 range: 0..7
access_t y = static_cast<access_t>(8);   // undefined behavior since CWG1766
```

That makes it clear that "range" is tied to the named enumerator values, not the full width of any integer type.  Assuming that cppreference example is an accurate reflection of the ISO standard, of course, that implies that explicit or implicit conversion can't legally produce an `enum` object with a value that isn't accounted for.

Comment: Something related, you can use [`std::unreachable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable)(C++23) and other compiler specific functions like `__builtin_unreachable` to encourage optimizations, even if you didn't have all cases specified.

Comment: @AviBerger This is not limited to floating-point types. http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you. The standard is a better source than cppreference and your citation's wording is different and clearer then full quote from cppreference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I guess in theory they could. There is no standard-sanctioned way to reach the `default`.

As mentioned on the cppreference page, the standard essentially says in [[dcl.enum]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.enum#8.sentence-2) that the possible values of an enumeration without fixed underlying type are zero to, exclusive, the smallest power of two able to fit all of the declared enumerator's values. Casting from the underlying type to values outside this range via `static_cast` is explicitly undefined behavior.

There may be some room to argue about `memcpy`/`std::bit_cast` from the underlying type to the enumeration, but I don't think that works out either. The linked standard passage seems to define the values of the enumeration exclusively, so it is not possible for object representations to represent any additional values (assuming they are valid object representations of the enumeration to begin with).

The standard currently doesn't even guarantee same representation as the underlying type for the values that the enumeration does have (although that may be a defect).

However, it wouldn't be compatible with C where all values of the underlying type are allowed. Since the smallest possible underlying type is `char` which is at least 8 bits wide, it will always be possible to reach the `default` in C.

So I don't expect any compiler to consider the `default` unreachable without additional knowledge of the argument's range.

Enumerations with fixed underlying type (which includes all `enum class`) are specified differently and guaranteed to support all values of the underlying type, as is the case in C for all enumerations.

Comment: So an enum with 63 different cases can most likely not ignore the default case, but one with 64 different cases might. In that case I’d say an optimisation is pointless and dangerous.

Comment: @gnasher729 It could be made use of in general for jump tables. Without assuming that values outside the range aren't possible, the compiler needs to add a check whether the value is outside the range of the jump table. If the limited range would be used, the compiler could just layout a jump table for that size (largest enumerator value rounded to power of two) and ignore the possibility of the value lying above it, getting rid of the extra conditional.

Comment: @user17732522 That's a good point about jump tables. It seems to me that would be the more insidious case where the default statement is defined for some non-enumeration values but not others. Though as you say, using enum class or fixed type enums would avoid all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers are very aggressive with assumptions that undefined behaviour doesn’t happen (and therefore optimise code away). But in C, it is just too easy to create an enum value that doesn’t match any case. And the code that you showed was explicitly intended to detect incorrect values.

I have never seen or heard of a compiler optimising this case away. Different in a language like Swift where setting an enum to a value that isn’t mentioned as a case is very , very hard to do.